# Разъясните пожалуйста, что значит *&?

Tags: c++

Это передача ссылки по адресу? Зачем она нужна, где применяется, чем отличается от обычной ссылки или указателя.

Comment: c++ является контекстно зависимым языком, поэтому для таких вопросов необходимо приводить [mcve]

Comment: Без контекста ничего не скажешь. Например, `int x; int y = *&x;` это одно, а `int *&x = y;` - уже совсем другое. Так что - "огласите весь список", т.е. приведите фрагмент кода.

Comment: я так понял, что передача это как для аргумента в функцию. @Harry

Comment: @AlexGlebe Вот пусть ТС это и подтвердит, приведя тот код, который так его удивил...

Answer (score 1):

`int` - целое число

`int *`  - указатель на целое число

`int * &` - ссылка на указатель на целое число

```
int i ; // переменная целого числа
int * p = & i ; // указатель на переменную i
int * & s = p ; // ссылка на указатель p

int j ; // другая переменная целого числа
s = & j ; // меняет указатель который по ссылке указывал на p на адрес 
          // другой переменной. p раньше указывал на i , теперь на j
```

Ссылка на указатель применяется например как аргумент в функции, которая меняет этот указатель.

```
int i ;
int j ;
int * p = & i ;
...
void fun(int * & x) {
  x = & j ; }
... 
fun(p); // меняет указатель p, чтобы указывал на j
```